# Use GoQuery to modify style?

Tags: go, goquery

In GoQuery, how do you use it properly to modify the style of a certain element in a loop? I am currently unable to find it in the documentation.

```
doc.Find("class[id=needsclick]").Each(func(i int, s *goquery.Selection) { 
 // not too sure what to put here

        })
```

Comment: Show us what you've tried and where you got stuck. Aim for a [mcve].

Comment: @icza Modified, thanks.